# name of technologies that BlogEngine.NET uses

Tags: blogengine.net

I am looking to modify this open source blog, and I wanted to know which technologies that this is built on i.e, MVC, Entity Framework etc

Answer (score 1):

You can see on their github repository: 
https://github.com/rxtur/BlogEngine.NET

That it uses:

- ASP.net 4.5+
- angularJS
- Bootstrap
- The librairies: ajaxminify, blogml, nugets, syntaxhighlighter
- ...

For instance, you can look at: 
https://github.com/rxtur/BlogEngine.NET/blob/master/BlogEngine/BlogEngine.NET/packages.config